# chef. how can I reliably test for, and store the result of, a postgres database existence check?

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, conditional-statements

For each of the following 3 databases I want to check if the database exists.

`"psql -d #{dbname} -c 'SELECT 1 as check_;'"` on its own, works as expected and returns `0` if it exists and `2` if it doesn't.

But getting chef to do something with that test is difficult.

I can't use guard `not_if` because I really need to control a number of steps from that existence:

- load the database
- create user
- grant user
- etc...

So what I was really planning to do was to do a `next` and iterate to the next database in the loop if it existed, via `next`.

```
%w{ hcm91dmo ksysdb pgfin92}.each do |dbname|


  begin 
    execute "check_exist_db" do
      command "psql -d #{dbname} -c 'SELECT 1 as check_;'"
      user "postgres"
      ignore_failure true
      dbexist2 = true
    end
    dbexist1 = true
    Chef::Log.info("jlp:execute OK")
  rescue 
    Chef::Log.info("jlp:execute rescue")
    dbexist1 = false
    dbexist2 = false
  end
```

The `rescue` doesn't seem to matter much.  And I still get errors despite the `ignore_failure`:

```
==> default: STDERR: psql: FATAL:  database "pgfin92" does not exist
==> default: ---- End output of psql -d pgfin92 -c 'SELECT 1 as check_;' ----
==> default: Ran psql -d pgfin92 -c 'SELECT 1 as check_;' returned 2; ignore_failure is set, continuing
==> default:
==> default:     ================================================================================
==> default:     Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[check_exist_db]'
==> default:     ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default:     Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default:     ------------------------------------
==> default:     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
==> default:     ---- Begin output of psql -d pgfin92 -c 'SELECT 1 as check_;' ----
==> default:     STDOUT:
==> default:     STDERR: psql: FATAL:  database "pgfin92" does not exist
==> default:     ---- End output of psql -d pgfin92 -c 'SELECT 1 as check_;' ----
==> default:     Ran psql -d pgfin92 -c 'SELECT 1 as check_;' returned 2
```

For those who are curious, I am using Chef to gradually tweak a server to its desired state.  A lot of time the code and configuration changes a bit, but without the databases needing any updates.  In fact, since the databases get updated by user input, I want user changes to persist through Chef runs.  So I don't want to drop and reload the databases without a good reason.

#### Solution, adapted from @coderanger 's answer:

```
#chef load: save list of databases that don't exist
dbtodo = []

%w{ hcm91dmo ksysdb pgfin92}.each do |dbname|
  
  #note that you need to specify a user that works for postgres
  if (shell_out("psql", "-d", dbname, "-c", "SELECT 1 as check_;",:user => "postgres").error?)
    dbtodo.push(dbname)
  end

end

#now, just loop thru databases that didn't exist
#I know I need to perform all the actions on each one of these.
dbtodo.each do |dbname|

  #execute phase, no conditional needed because we're running off
  #saved database list
  postgresql_database dbname do
    connection postgresql_connection_info
    action :create
  end

...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute` is a resource, which doesn't really help when you want to get some kind of result from running the command. What you want is to use the `shell_out` helper method:

```
shell_out("psql", "-d", dbname, "-c", "SELECT 1 as check_;").error?
```

or something similar to that. Unlike a resource which has the usual two-pass loading and execution process, `shell_out` (and `shell_out!`) are imperative Ruby code so when that line runs, it runs the command and gets you the result right then. Check out https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for more info on the loading model and why your example doesn't work.

Comment: txs. will look.  and yes, the 2 step model is something I know I am insufficiently clear on.

Comment: Also it worth noting that `not_if "foo"` and `not_if { shell_out("foo").error? }` mean the same thing (unless I got the bool-ness backwards, but you know what I mean). So you might actually still want a `not_if`/`only_if` guard and just use a const for the actual command so you don't repeat it in a bunch of places.